# How to modify permissions with FileACL wfor two users

Tags: permissions

I need to apply permissions to files and folders with Fileacl for two users.  This is an example of one user:

```
FILEACL "C:\MyDocuments2\Web" /S "%MachineName%\ASPNET":RrRaRepWwAWaWeX /S "CREATOR OWNER":U/RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO/RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "%MachineName%\IUSR_%MachineName%":RrRaRepWwAWaWeX /S "%MachineName%\%UserName%":RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE":RrRaRepWwAWaWe  /PROTECT
```

I need to apply the above line to user IUSR and user IIS_USERS. 
I'm trying to create a bat file to apply permissions to all folders needed in IIS 7.5 running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

That example command line already sets permissions for three different users.  Or at least `ASPNET` and `IUSR_%MachineName%` are definitely user accounts and `%UserName%` presumably is too.  For that matter, as far as `FILEACL` is concerned, both the built-in account `NETWORK SERVICE` and the special security identifier `CREATOR OWNER` are all just trustees the same as the user accounts, it has no reason to care what sort of trustee you're using.

So far as I can see the documentation does not suggest that there is any limit to the number of trustees you can include in the ACL via the `/S` option so there shouldn't be any problem, just add whatever additional trustees you want, e.g.,

```
FILEACL "C:\MyDocuments2\Web" /S "%MachineName%\ASPNET":RrRaRepWwAWaWeX /S "CREATOR OWNER":U/RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO/RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "%MachineName%\IUSR_%MachineName%":RrRaRepWwAWaWeX /S "%MachineName%\IUSR":RrRaRepWwAWaWeX /S  "%MachineName%\%UserName%":RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE":RrRaRepWwAWaWe  /PROTECT
```

*Nitpicker's corner:* the `CREATOR OWNER` identifier does have special semantics and there may be cases where it makes sense for an ACL-manipulating tool to treat it as a special case.   However, I don't see anything in the documentation to suggest that this particular tool does.